# How to get text from between characters in oracle sql

Tags: text, substr

Hi this is my first post and I'm also new to sql. I am trying to extract text from within a string

I have a table column that looks like this

`site - abc - left`
`site - def - left`
`site - ghi - right - inner`
`site - jkl - right - inner`
`site - mno`
`site - pqr`

I need a query that would return text inbetween the first two '-' but as per example some only have one '-'.

For example.

`abc`
`def`
`ghi`
`jkl`
`mno`
`pqr`

Any help greatfully accepted

The code I have been working with only gives me the first column 'site'.

`SELECT SUBSTR(site.description,1,instr(site.description,'-',1,1)-1) AS loc`
`FROM table`

Comment: Do you want to return those with only one `-`, even though they're not between two `-`? And what about 'right'? It's between two `-`'s, why are they not being returned?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code that you're currently working with.

Comment: yes i need to return both those with one `-` and two `-`. I am not intrested next along eg. 'right'.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose your data resides in a tabled named test_n with only column val with above values as mentioned in your question, the query is:

```
select val
     , instr(val, '-', 1,1) + 1 START_POS
     , instr(val, '-',1,2) END_POS
     , substr(val, instr(val, '-', 1,1) + 1, decode(instr(val, '-',1,2),0,length(val)+1,instr(val, '-',1,2) ) - instr(val, '-', 1,1)-1 ) result
FROM test_n;
```

Comment: Is there a way you can still add another function that trims the first character from the output? From the OP's example, the result will be: bc, ef, hi..

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked yet, but i think this would work for you

```
substr(var1,1,instr(site.description,'-',1,1)+1-instr(site.description,'-',1,2)-1)
```

it should work,if it did not just need a little change.let me know the result